# MySQL - Export data, and ignore primary key. Then import using auto increment

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, auto-increment

I have a table with primary key in auto-increment column "id" and a column "data"

Contents of table:

```
id | data
1  | aaaaa
2  | bbbbb
3  | whatever :P
5  | dang
99 | hello
```

As you can see there are 5 rows. the id's are 1,2,3,5,99 (there are NO id = 4 or id = 6 to 98).

How can i export this table, and then import it in another table (same structure of course) and the id's will get the values 1,2,3,4,5 instead of 1,2,3,5,99.

(or import them in a table that has already data, and the imported ids will take whatever values are from that table's auto_increment value and go on?)

Note: If there is a solution specific for PhpMyAdmin its welcome.

-Sorry for bad english! (Ops Feel free to edit)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a table with the same layout. Then:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (data) SELECT data FROM old_table;
```

This will copy only the data fields into the new table. Since the id column is auto_increment, it will add ids counting from one upwards.

Comment: (Facepalm) ...aw so obvious! Where is my mind? Thank you Mantriur!

Comment: That will work. If you want to control the ordering of the rows in the new table you can do so with an ORDER BY clause: `INSERT INTO new_table (data) SELECT data FROM old_table ORDER BY id;`

Comment: @Mantriur : What if there are more than one columns in the table? Me too stuck with same problem. The problem is i have got 20 tables and each table contains primary key and which may or may not be a foreign key. Columns in each table may vary from 5 to 10. Any solutions?

Comment: @Gapchoos: You can do any number of columns, like this: `INSERT INTO newTable (column1, column2, column3) SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM oldTable;`. You will have to modify the query for each table individually.

Answer (score 5):

```
INSERT INTO newTable (data) SELECT data FROM oldTable;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Travesty3! Mantriur was some seconds faster though :) 

(i wonder why you both been downvoted? - i voted you up again)

Comment: @Sharky: Yeah, he beat me by about 8 seconds, and his answer was more descriptive. Also not sure why we were downvoted, but thanks! Please make sure to mark his answer as your accepted solution as well!

Comment: @Sharky It wouldn't hurt to accept one of the answers either.

Comment: @tombom i need to wait some seconds... im waiting here to accept ;) 

...done